# Load TGPBitmap from MemoryStream

Tags: delphi, gdi+

I have been asked to correct an issue (not related to this question) in a legacy Delphi program.  After fixing some issues with missing components, I am now stuck with some GDI Plus functionality, which stops me from compiling the program.  One of the functions where this is used is:

```
function TDownLoadItem.LoadRawBitmapFromStream(var bm: TBitmap): Boolean;
var
  image: TGPBitmap;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Content.Size = 0 then
    exit;

  // NOTE: Content is a TMemoryStream, declared globally.
  image := GDIPlusHelper.LoadBitmapFromStream(Content); // <== This is where the problem is....

  try
    bm.Width := image.GetWidth;
    bm.Height := image.GetHeight;
    with TGPGraphics.Create(bm.Canvas.Handle) do
      try
        DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.GetWidth, image.GetHeight);
        Result := True;
      finally
        Free;
      end;
  finally
    image.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I think (not sure) the last Delphi version used was 2006, I am on Delphi Rio 10.3.

Online I have managed to find GDI+ 1.2, but this does not solve the problem. The procedure LoadBitmapFromStream does not exit in these libraries. GDIPlusHelper was apparently renamed to GDIPlusHelpers and most code has changed from classes to interfaces. I suspect an older edition of the GDI Plus libraries were used, but I cannot find these.

Reworking the code would be too complex as it would require Content to be an IStream instead of a TMemoryStream.  Also, simply using a TBitmap is not feasible either as other code (not shown) uses functionality specific to TGPBitmap (e.g. RotateFlip).

Any suggestions on how to fix/work around this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What image format is into the TMemoryStream?

Comment: I presume Bitmap or PNG.  image:= LoadBitmapFromPNGStream(Content) in if-statement was commented out so that only image := GDIPlusHelper.LoadBitmapFromStream(Content); was left.

Comment: It was stated that LoadBitmapFromStream works fine with PNG.  Apparently it doesn't matter whether it's bmp or PNG.  Of course I can only test this once I can compile the program ;-)

Comment: I have some code that takes an in memory bitmap (3x8 bits for RGB) and produce a TGPBitmap. You'd have to load memory from your TMemoryStream, decoding the file format if the TMemoryStream content is the same as an equivalent file. Is this interesting for you?

Comment: I have now "solved it" by first creating a TStreamAdapter to Content (the TMemoryStream) and then create image (TGPBitmap) from the StreamAdapter.  This compiles so I'll make some further adjustments and then test if it indeed works as required.